# How to set json data into jquery 1.7 datatable

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I'm using jquery 1.7.1, as this is my old project so I can't change it. I am facing problem in setting json data return by my controller to ajax call made by javascript into datatable.
following is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : "myController",
    dataType : 'json',
    data : 'operation=getUploaded&filename=' + filename,
    success : function(data) {

        console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<data<<<<<<<<<<<", data.Data[0]);
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "aoData": data.Data[0],
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "id" },
                { "mDataProp": "point" },
                { "mDataProp": "floor" },
                { "mDataProp": "custAccNo" },
                { "mDataProp": "data" }
        ]

        });
    }
});
```

here is my json returned:

```
{
   "Data": [{
       "id": 4534534,
       "point": "45",
       "floor": "345",
       "custAccNo": "000000001",
       "data": "ABC",
       "fileName": "23rbc.rti",
       "grid": "001"
   }]
}
```

Here is my table in my jsp:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>point</th>
                <th>floor</th>
                <th>custAccNo</th>
                <th>data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any advise?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Please post the exact problem that you are facing.

Comment: empty data table is displayed, no error. @Hector

Comment: the correct setting is `aaData`, not `aoData` ...

Answer (score 0):

Your array is `data.Data` not `data.Data[0]` which is the first object in the array